# Pass values ​MySQL query using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

When making a query, I show the results in a table, each row has a button. By pressing it I move the information of the selected row to a textarea. The problem is that when all the buttons have the same identifier, java always takes the first row.

https://jsfiddle.net/a50ue2bw/

```js
function calcular() {
    $('#pedido').val($('#pedido').val() + $(this).closest('tr').find('#cantidad').val());
    $('#pedido').val($('#pedido').val() + " "+ $(this).closest('tr').find('select option:selected').attr('value'));
    $('#pedido').val($('#pedido').val() + " "+ $(this).attr('nombre')+ "\n");
    
    var newPrice = parseFloat($('body').find('#categoria option:selected').attr('precio'));
    var cantidadt = parseFloat($('body').find('#cantidad').val());
    $("#cuenta").val(parseFloat($("#cuenta").val())+parseFloat(newPrice*cantidadt)+' €');
    $("#save").val(parseFloat($("#save").val())+parseFloat(newPrice*cantidadt));
}
```

Comment: The `id` attribute MUST be UNIQUE to work properly. They are like the keys to an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your on-click event listener via jQuery and use `this` to access the button that was pressed.

```
$('.button').on('click',calcular);

function calcular() {
    $('#pedido').val($('#pedido').val() + $('#cantidad').val());
    $('#pedido').val($('#pedido').val() + " "+ $(this).closest('tr').find('select option:selected').attr('value'));
    $('#pedido').val($('#pedido').val() + " "+ $(this).attr('nombre')+ "\n");
    
    var newPrice = parseFloat($('body').find('#categoria option:selected').attr('precio'));
    var cantidadt = parseFloat($('body').find('#cantidad').val());
    $("#cuenta").val(parseFloat($("#cuenta").val())+parseFloat(newPrice*cantidadt)+' €');
    $("#save").val(parseFloat($("#save").val())+parseFloat(newPrice*cantidadt));

}
```

Comment: Work, but i have the same problem with the select field.

Comment: see my edit, don't match the select tag by ID (which must be unique) but travel up the DOM tree to find it.

Comment: Ok, thanks. In the number field, work, but in the line to get the float of the value of the number field doesn't work.

Comment: Yeah, will leave that as an exercise for you, it's just the same as in the number field.

Comment: I can't get it to work, help!